# How to set IntelliJ IDEA Tip of the day daily

Tags: intellij-idea

I really like the Tips in IntelliJ IDEA to learn more about its helping functions. But I tend to start the IDE multiple times a day and get a new message every time. Then the same messages are getting annoying and I usually wont even read them anymore.

So I would like to set the tip of the day to daily as the name suggests.
I didnt find a setting in the program or on their help pages.
Is there a config file or some other possibility to do so?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such option. What you can do is disable this window.

To do this, click on **Help** > **Tip of the day** and uncheck *Show tips on startup*.

Whenever you want to see a new tip navigate to this same place and read as many as you wish.

But no, there is no option to display it only once a day. It shows up whenever the IDE is started.